# how to use Laravel-mix in laravel 10

Tags: php, npm, webpack, laravel-mix, laravel-10

cant seem to configur the `laravel-mix` package.

Hey,I want to use the `laravel-mix` package in laravel 10, but i cant seem to configur it properly because when i run npx mix i keep getting a error that says that i need to change my webpack.mix.js to webpack.mix.cjs but when i do that i still cant use npx mix, can somewone tell me how to configur the `laravel-mix` package it would realy help.

npx mix error:

```
npx mix    
[webpack-cli] Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\casro\Documents\Programeren\Laravel-projects\CasRovers-CMS\webpack.mix.js from C:\Users\casro\Documents\Programeren\Laravel-projects\CasRovers-CMS\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js not supported.
webpack.mix.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead either rename webpack.mix.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in C:\Users\casro\Documents\Programeren\Laravel-projects\CasRovers-CMS\package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

    at module.exports (C:\Users\casro\Documents\Programeren\Laravel-projects\CasRovers-CMS\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js:11:5)
    at loadConfigByPath (C:\Users\casro\Documents\Programeren\Laravel-projects\CasRovers-CMS\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1439:37)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async WebpackCLI.loadConfig (C:\Users\casro\Documents\Programeren\Laravel-projects\CasRovers-CMS\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1454:35)
    at async WebpackCLI.createCompiler (C:\Users\casro\Documents\Programeren\Laravel-projects\CasRovers-CMS\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1785:22)
    at async WebpackCLI.runWebpack (C:\Users\casro\Documents\Programeren\Laravel-projects\CasRovers-CMS\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1890:20)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\casro\Documents\Programeren\Laravel-projects\CasRovers-CMS\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:912:21)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\casro\Documents\Programeren\Laravel-projects\CasRovers-CMS\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1372:13) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

package.json:

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "mix": "npx mix"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.23.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.3",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.69.5",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0",
        "webpack": "^5.89.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
        "jquery": "^3.7.1"
    }
}
```

webpack.mix.js:

```php
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

if someone can help me with this i realy appreciate it

Comment: so the error message says to use dynamic import, can you try `let mix = (await import('laravel-mix')).default;` instead of `let mix = require('laravel-mix');`

Comment: Hi Adi, thanks for your input! I noticed the import statement is the same in both suggestions. Did you mean to propose a different import statement, or is there something specific you think I should change?

Comment: What do you mean by same import statement? I think i had edited the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve got it working now, all I had to do is remove `"type": "module",` from the package.json

Answer (score 0):

remove "type": "module" is work for npx mix for first time and then does not work for the second time.